# I have an array of thousands of items with a URL attribute. How do I create a button for each item in the array that opens an iframe to the URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, for-loop

Since there are thousands of items in the array, I can't create `iframe` tags for EVERY item (for loading's sake), so how do I make it so there's only one `iframe` in the DOM, but when you press a button with the corresponding item's name, open up the iframe with the corresponding URL?

---

## Ex:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Thomas Jefferson",
      "url": "https://thomas-jefferson.com"
    }
    // Insert a few thousand more objects with the same format
  ]
}
```

Generate a button for every item in the array:

```
for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var item = "<button>" + data[i].name + "</button>";
  $('#list').append(item)
}
```

DOM looks like this:

```
<div id="list"></div>

<iframe id="url-output"></iframe>
```

---

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just have the dynamically created button change the `src` of the one `iframe`.

```js
// You need to assign an identifier to the object
let obj = {
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Example.com",
      "url": "https://www.example.com"
    },
    {
      "name": "TTS",
      "url": "https://techtrainsolutions.com"
    }    
    // Insert a few thousand more objects with the same format
  ]
}

// Use let for block scope and avoid the classic closure in a loop problem
for (let i=0; i < obj.data.length; i++) {
  var item = document.createElement("button");
  item.textContent = obj.data[i].name;
  // Set up event handler for the new button
  item.addEventListener("click", function(){
    $("iframe")[0].src = obj.data[i].url; // Point to correct URL
  });
  $('#list').append(item)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="list"></div>
<iframe id="url-output"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use event delegation on the `#list`, and when the nth button is clicked, access the nth element in the `data` array, and extract the URL in question:

```
const $buttons = $('#list > button');
$('#list').on('click', 'button', function() {
  const index = $buttons.index(this);
  const { url } = obj.data[index];
  $('#url-output').prop('src', url);
});
```